# If $\ (f(x))^2 = 1 $ then $\ f(x) = 1 $ or $\ f(x) = - 1 $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $\ f(x) $ be continuous for every $\ x $ and $\ (f(x))^2 = 1 $  Prove $\ f(x) = 1 $ **or** $\ f(x) = -1 $ for every x.

I think if $\ (f(x))^2 = 1  \rightarrow f(x)f(x) = 1 \rightarrow f(x) = 1 $ or $\ f(x) = -1 $ and $\ f(x) $ is continuous so for every $\ x : \lim f(x) = f(x) $

I'm not sure how to proceed from here?

Comment: IVT${}{}{}{}{}$?

Comment: think graphically for condtion of continuity.

Comment: Notice the domain of $f$ must be an interval, otherwise the sign-function restricted to $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ would be a counterexample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix $x_0$, then by your argument $f(x_0) = 1$ or $f(x_0)=-1$.

If $f(x_0)=1$ we shall prove that for every other $x$ we have $f(x)=1$. If by contradiction there exists $y_0$ such that $f(y_0)=-1$. Then by the intermediate value Theorem there exists a point $z_0$ between $x_0$ and $y_0$ such that $f(z_0) =0$ which is a contradiction to the fact that $f^2(z_0)=1$.

The same if $f(x_0)=-1$.

Just a note: I added the tag real-analysis to your question. This is because you implicitly assume that $f$ takes real values. If $f$ is a complex function then this argument won't work. In fact $f(x) = e^{2\pi i x}$ is a counter-example.

Answer (score 1):

According to the intermediate value theorem if a continuous function assumes two different values, say $1$ and $-1$, then it has to assume every value between $1$ and $-1$

Since your function is only assuming $\pm 1$ it does not take other values between $\pm 1$ so it is a constant function.